# Experiencing freeze during OpenCMS setup

Tags: tomcat7, opencms

Anyone ever experienced something like that? I'm installing OpenCMS 8.5.0. for evaluation, running on Tomcat 7x, and during the 8th step of setup (Installing Modules), the process freezes - I've got stuck for a long time in a same line (I left it the way it was, and hung out for coffee for 30-40 minutes), without any update.

What have you done?

Thanks,

*** **Edited from this line** ***

I've tried to refresh the page (After coming back from my coffee break), and it only cleared the logs. So I stopped the server and re-started it again. The process started from beginning (I had to drop the database and create it again), the processes freezes again, I waited some time, a tried to refresh the page sometimes, again I faced logs inside the 'textarea' the being cleared, after some tries, the process was finally finished.

Anyone have faced the same experience?

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

How much max. heap is assigned to the Tomcat? 64MB as the default standard? Eventually tried to increase that parameter?

Can ou check the log (WEB-INF/logs/opencms.log) or the catalina.out - do you see any errors in there?

I have OpenCms 8.5 running on Tomcat7 without any problems.

Which OS are you on? Windows, Linux, Mac?